# Why is $(document).scrollTop() not equal to $(document).height() at the bottom of the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I calculated the ratio of scroll position and the height of the html document using

```
var filled = ($(document).scrollTop() / $(document).height());
```

I get 0.8596615031325553 instead of 1 at the bottom of the document , why is it so??
I have to use this ratio dynamically somewhere else in my code , but since its giving the unexpected value I can't use it.  What should I do??

Comment: The difference between the two should be `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: So I need to add `window.innerHeight` to `$(document).scrollTop()` to get the expected value??

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/v52qkxvo/

Comment: Thankyou brother it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).scrollTop()` returns how far down the **top** of the current view is from the top of the page (i.e. how far the user has *scrolled down*). `$(document).height())` returns the hight of the complete page, from the top-most pixel to the bottom pixel.

To compensate this, you could do something like this:

```
var filled = (($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) / $(document).height());
```

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: It is also not working , it gives 1.843853431717268 at the bottom of the document

Comment: Not even if you copy the exact line?

Comment: `var filled = (($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight) / $(document).height());` this works fine..

Comment: @ThomsoIitr Okay then just use that. Apparently it returns a different value than jQuery's function.